# Multiple file upload using ajax in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to upload multiple images from one input field and want to send form-data with images and action via ajax. Below I am sharing my code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var ajax_url = 'admin-ajax.php';
    // When the Upload button is clicked...
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#upload_multiImages', function(e){
     e.preventDefault;

     var fd = new FormData();
        var files_data = jQuery('.files-data'); // The <input type="file" /> field
        
        // Loop through each data and create an array file[] containing our files data.
        jQuery.each($(files_data), function(i, obj) {
         
         jQuery.each(obj.files,function(j,file){
          fd.append('files[' + j + ']', file);
         })
        });
        // our AJAX identifier
        fd.append('action', 'cvf_upload_files');  
        jQuery.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: ajax_url,
         data: fd,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
                jQuery('.upload-response').html(response); // Append Server Response
              }
            });
      });
  });
```

```html
<input name="my_file_upload[]" id="my_file_upload" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept = "image/*" class="files-data form-control multi with-preview" value="Drag and Drop" />
      <input name="all_vendor_file" type="hidden" value="<?php //echo implode(',', $vendor_images);?>">
     
     <button type="submit" name="upload" id="upload_multiImages">Upload</button>
          
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But in response I am only getting action files are not appending, due to which I am not able to get files data over ajax function.

Comment: please show how you are accessing files in php after ajax operation and you dont need `files[' + j + ']` as `files[]` is sufficient

Comment: $fids = array();
  if( $_FILES ){ 
   $files = $_FILES["files"]; 
   foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
    if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
     $file = array( 
      'name' => $files['name'][$key],
      'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
      'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
      'error' => $files['error'][$key],
      'size' => $files['size'][$key]
     ); 
     $_FILES = array ("files" => $file); 
     foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {              
      $fids[] = media_handle_upload($file,0); 
     }
    } 
   } 
  }

Comment: I tested your jQuery code it is working fine for me, may be the problem is in functions.php, where you defined cvf_upload_files, can you show those two add_action statements needed to perform ajax in wp ?

Comment: Try dumping values  `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: function cvf_upload_files(){
if( $_FILES ){ 
$files = $_FILES["files"]; 
foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
$file = array( 
'name' => $files['name'][$key],
'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
'error' => $files['error'][$key],
'size' => $files['size'][$key]
); 
$_FILES = array ("files" => $file); 

} 
} 
}



}

Comment: I mean these statements `add_action("wp_ajax_cvf_upload_files", "cvf_upload_files");` and
`add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_cvf_upload_files", "cvf_upload_files"); `